# Add around 1000 keys to a plist

Tags: plist, key

I have about 1000 adresses (name, address, city, country, long, lat) i want to add to my plist.

Is there an easy way to do it without having to do it manually?

I have all required info in a tab seperated file or excel and i could reformat this to insert code.

Answer (score 0):

The plist is just a fancy xml file, If you can format it, you can just copy paste it into the plist's source file

Answer (score 0):

It's not really worth spending a lot of time on this sort of thing. Use a macro in the tool of your choice (Excel, Notepad++, etc).